# RailsでBoolean型のテストデータの値

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby on Railsで開発をしています。
今、テストデータを入れるため、Seedファイルを作るためのspec/factories/xxx.rbの中身を作成中です。
ここでBoolean型にはどんな値を入れたらいいかよくわかりません。
最初はTrue/Falseの文字列を入れようとしましたが、数字の1/0を入れるべきではないかと..
今のコードは下記の通りです。

is_verified { %w(true false).sample }

下記の通りに直した方がいいですかね。

is_verified { %w(1 0).sample }

Answer (score 1):

true/false、どちらの値でもいいなら

```
is_verified { [true, false].sample }
```

のように書けばいいと思います。（文字列ではなく、true/falseそのものの値をセットする）

が、真偽値が実行するたびにフラフラと変わると、毎回テストが成功したり失敗したり、結果が不安定になりそうなので、

```
is_verified true
```

または

```
is_verified false
```

とどちらか一方に固定した方が普通は安全だと思います。